# Time series numeric again after indexing?

Tags: r, time-series

I wanted to cut a quarterly time series and did the following:

```
cuttedts <- initialts[time(initialts) > 1984.00]
```

which worked inasmuch as I got all data after the first quarter of 1984. Strikingly

```
is.ts(initialts)
# returns TRUE
```

while

```
is.ts(cuttedts)
# returns FALSE
```

What did I do wrong, should I use subset? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `window` function to extract a subset of a time series.

For example :

```
R> myts <- ts(data=1:40, start=2001, end=c(2010,4), frequency=4)
R> myts
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2001    1    2    3    4
2002    5    6    7    8
2003    9   10   11   12
2004   13   14   15   16
2005   17   18   19   20
2006   21   22   23   24
2007   25   26   27   28
2008   29   30   31   32
2009   33   34   35   36
2010   37   38   39   40
```

And then :

```
R> subts <- window(myts, start=c(2005,2), end=c(2008,3))
R> subts
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2005        18   19   20
2006   21   22   23   24
2007   25   26   27   28
2008   29   30   31
```

The result is still a `ts` object :

```
R> is.ts(subts)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thx juba. RTFM ran2. I was just about to post this. hopefully it helps someone else :)